# change profle pic logged in user php

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am creating a website with user register and login system. Users can give several options for in the database by registrering. But now I add a option to upload your profile pic. But I can only change that one thats mentioned in the script and not the user thats logged in. Can someone help me?

```
<?PHP
require_once("./include/fg_membersite.php");
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login.php");
    exit;
}

?>

<?php session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = "ademd";
?>
 
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"images/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
    $con = mysqli_connect("voetbaltransfermarkt.nl.mysql","voetbaltransfer","","voetbaltransfer");
    $q = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE fgusers3 SET image = '".$_FILES['file']['name']."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a link to profile picture in your database table to display profile picture and then in my profile page put an UPDATE query of mysql for updating link to that uploaded picture.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer but I have already a link to display the pic. But the problem is as you can see above mentioned this wil show or change only the user "ademd" what I want is to change the pic for the user that's logged in at the moment.